# OSX/Mac: Modify system popup menu using accessibility api

Tags: macos, accessibility

I'm writing an application that uses some of the accessibility apis to make using a Mac a little easier for certain people.

I know how to add items to the system-level application popup menu. What I am trying to figure out is if there is a way to modify other items in that menu. For example, when someone command-clicks (right-clicks) on their Desktop and then highlights the Paste menuitem I would like to automatically display additional ui that shows a preview of whatever is on the pasteboard.

I understand that this type of functionality isn't for everyone but it would be very helpful to my users.

Thanks,
LT